# Ошибка при запуске решения в студии 2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-basic

Имеется решение в студии 2008, состоящее из двух проектов.

1. библиотека классов
2. само приложение к которому привязан первый проект

при запуске вылетает ошибка

> Ошибка    1   не удалось скопировать файл "obj\Debug\XLibrary.dll" в
>   "bin\Debug\XLibrary.dll". Отказано в доступе по пути
>   "obj\Debug\XLibrary.dll". XLibrary

Нахожусь под учетной записью админа в win 8, запуск студии от админа ничего не дает.

После закрытия студии, и открытия заново, компилируется и запускается, но до первого изменения в коде, после чего появляется эта же ситуация.

Очистка/пересоздание проектов/решения ничего не дает.
Подскажите что делать...

**UPDATE**

Собственно сам процесс студии и держит эту библиотеку, поиск через *ProcessExplorer* 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у меня было очень похожее. Причина оказалась в антивирусе. Он видел, что файл поменялся и начинал его проверять. Но антивирусные компании ещё не научились отрабатывать нормально подобные ситуации и держат файл залоченным. Более того, всякие process explorer'ы не показывают, что они их держат (и это логично - нормальный антивирус не сильно отличается от вируса).

Решение простое - исключить каталог с проектом из области проверки антивируса. Более того, даже компилироваться быстрее начало.

Comment: Ураааа! Оформляйте в виде ответа. Отключил доктора веба, заработало!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня было очень похожее. Причина оказалась в антивирусе. Он видел, что файл поменялся и начинал его проверять. А проверяет он его долго. Но антивирусные компании ещё не научились отрабатывать нормально подобные ситуации и держат файл залоченным. Более того, всякие process explorer'ы не показывают, что они их держат (и это логично - нормальный антивирус не сильно отличается от нормального вируса - используются абсолютно те же "тайные хода").

Решение оказалось очень простое - исключить каталог с проектом из области проверки "налету" антивируса. Более того, даже компилироваться быстрее начало. Сами сорцы исключать не нужно.

Возможно, сюда сейчас набегут представители антивирусных компаний и скажут "нельзя так делать, у вируса будет место, где можно спрятаться" или "а мы присекаем вирусописателей на корню, ещё при взлете". Ничего подобного. Вирусописатели обычно не держат антивирусы активными. Только для проверки своей поделки. А обычные программисты страдают.

P.S. ещё было весело, когда антивирус решил, что exe содержит вирус (это было с делфи) и удалял exe сразу после компиляции. И приложение нельзя было запустить никак. Самое интересное - антивирус никак явно не сообщал, что он уже удалил. Только в логах обнаружил.

Comment: Большое спасибо! При добавлении обоих проектов в исключение, студия сперва вообще сошла с ума после включения доктора, не могла вообще что либо запустить и не видела даже проект библиотеки, но после перезагрузки винды все прекрасно работает.

Answer (score 0):

Вашу динамическую библиотеку что-то использует. Скорее всего, ваше же приложение, которое не завершило работу. Очистка не поможет, потому что система сборки проекта не может ни удалить, ни скопировать запущенный файл.

1. Убедитесь, что ваше приложение завершило работу. Посмотрите список процессов, там не должно быть вашей программы.
2. Если не помогло, посмотрите, какой процесс занял вашу библиотеку. Поиск по модулям и хэндлам есть в Process Explorer из SysInternals, а также в других утилитах.

Comment: При открытии проекта в процессах появляется этот процесс, он и держит библиотеку, но вот тогда вопрос почему он ее держит, в диспетчере задач программа после остановки проекта исчезает. `xmlProject.vshost.exe 5840 Выполняется svf 00  11 312 К vshost32.exe`

Comment: обновил топик, собственно процесс студии ее и держит, о чем собственно я и догадывался сразу...

Answer (score 0):

vshost.exe - это Visual Studio Hosting Process. Это прокси, через который студия запускает приложение, для внедрения некоторых отладочных фич. Его можно выключить:

Снимите чек Enable the Visual Studio hosting process в свойствах проекта-exe, на закладке Debugging.

Это уберет симптомы. Но сама по себе проблема скорее всего в вашем приложении - стоит посмотреть что происходит при выходе из него. Попробовать прервать отладку по Shift+F5, и посмотреть, останется ли после этого блокировка. Если не останется - отладить vshost.exe (через Attach To Process) и посмотреть, не выполяется ли там ваш код.

Comment: Снял галочки с обоих проектов, да _vhost_ теперь не видно в процессах, остался один чистый _denev_, но проблема осталась.

Comment: Shift+F5 перезапускает проект а не останавливает отладку в моем случае.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь в студиях до 2010-й были баги с блокировкой DLL самим дизайнером студии. Если руками переименовать залоченный файл (bin\Debug\XLibrary.dll -> bin\Debug\XLibrary.locked.dll) - приложение нормально стартует? если да, то я принесу автоматический костыль :(

Comment: нет, этот способ я уже пробовал, пробовал переименовывать и удалять, появляется вторая ошибка, что файл который пытаются копировать не найден, и тогда становится 2 ошибки и ничего кроме перезапуска студии не помогает (

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь какой именно файл вы переименовывали? в bin? или в obj? какая именно ошибка показывается после переименования?